# FBX SDK: how to transform point by matrix?

Tags: c++, 3d, fbx

I am writing a converter from [FBX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) to custom data format using [FBX SDK](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/). I need to get mesh vertices coordinates in the world coordinate system. I know how to get [mesh vertices coordinates](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_vector4_html) in the local coordinate system. First I should get mesh by GetMesh function in [FbxNode](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_node_html). Then I can get the vertices list directly from the [mesh](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_mesh_html).

Also I know how to get [transform matrix](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_a_matrix_html). I can do it by function EvaluateGlobalTransform from [FbxNode](http://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2019/ENU/?guid=FBX_Developer_Help_cpp_ref_class_fbx_node_html).

But I cannot understand how to transform the vertices by the matrix. I do not see operator* or operator() or any function which can transform a point by a matrix.

What is the proper way of getting point coordinates in world coordinates system?

Answer (score 0):

I just wound up using another math library to do the transformation. But yes it's somewhat strange that there's no simple transform point by matrix. MultT, MultS, MultR doesn't seem to do what I'd think they would.

Comment: Also struggling with this. Giving up and using Eigen...